# How to get Python error information for SyntaxError, NameError, etc. with Boost

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I am using Boost::Python to execute some scripts and when some some errors occur , I show the error messages in a log window with the line where the error happened. 
Unfortunately, I don't manage to get the line number for SyntaxError (and subclasses of this exception, such as IndentationError).

Using the code in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1418703/5421357

```
PyObject *ptype, *pvalue, *ptraceback;
PyErr_Fetch(&ptype, &pvalue, &ptraceback);
//pvalue contains error message
//ptraceback contains stack snapshot and many other information
//(see python traceback structure)

//Get error message
char *pStrErrorMessage = PyString_AsString(pvalue);
```

I managed to get the get all the error information from pvalue and ptraceback for non SyntaxError exceptions.

However, in the case of a SyntaxError, there's no traceback (ptraceback is NULL) from which you can get the information.

I need to know the line number, but I'm not sure if it's possible to get it with Boost.

**Is there any way to get the line number where the error happened?**

It would be enough for me to have the line number. The other information is not necessary (e.g. File) since I already have what I need (error type and description).

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that works here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16806477/5421357

In short, to get the line number where the Syntax Error occurred:

```
// Init code here ...

PyObject *res = PyRun_String(script_source,Py_file_input,main_dict,main_dict);      
if(res == NULL)
{
    PyObject *ptype = NULL, *pvalue = NULL, *ptraceback = NULL;
    PyErr_Fetch(&ptype,&pvalue,&ptraceback);
    PyErr_NormalizeException(&ptype,&pvalue,&ptraceback);

    char *msg, *file, *text;  
    int line, offset;  

    int res = PyArg_ParseTuple(pvalue,"s(siis)",&msg,&file,&line,&offset,&text);

    PyObject* line_no = PyObject_GetAttrString(pvalue,"lineno");
    PyObject* line_no_str = PyObject_Str(line_no);
    PyObject* line_no_unicode = PyUnicode_AsEncodedString(line_no_str,"utf-8", "Error");
    char *actual_line_no = PyBytes_AsString(line_no_unicode);  // Line number        
}
```