# Valgrind error and memory leaks with Python/C API

Tags: c++, python-2.7, memory-leaks, valgrind, python-c-api

I'm actually developping a game in C++ and trying to do the AI with a script langage. To do so, i choosed Python2 with Python/C api.
My AI is actually working but there is a big problem : when I run valgrind on my program, there is a lot of error and memory leaks. So, I would know if this happened because of my code or by the API ?

Here is a summary of my class AI :

```
 IA::IA()
{
  setenv("PYTHONPATH",".",1);
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
  pName = PyBytes_FromString((char*)"Test");
  pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
  pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
  pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, "push_f");
}

IA::~IA()
{
  Py_DECREF(pValue);
  Py_DECREF(pModule);
  Py_DECREF(pName);
  Py_Finalize();
}

void IA::LaunchIA(float x, float y, float z)
{
  PyObject *toSend;

  toSend = Py_BuildValue("(OOO)", TlistMob, TlistPlayer, pDPosIA);
  pResult = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, toSend);
  PyErr_Print();
  printf("return = %f\n", (float)PyInt_AsLong(pResult));

}
```

My (very) simple Python code :

```
def push_f(MobList, PlayerList, pos):
   return 0
```

And the valgrind error (x1000) :

```
==11602== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==11602== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==11602== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==11602== Command: ./a.out
==11602== 
==11602== Invalid read of size 4
==11602==    at 0x4FCE173: PyObject_Free (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==    by 0x4F02FC2: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==    by 0x4FBDE9A: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==    by 0x4F85BAD: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==    by 0x4F872FF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==    by 0x4F88559: PyImport_ImportModuleLevel (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==    by 0x4EFF697: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==    by 0x4F4B1E2: PyObject_Call (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==    by 0x5021446: PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==    by 0x4EF45C5: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==    by 0x502201B: PyEval_EvalCodeEx (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==    by 0x4EF0B88: PyEval_EvalCode (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==  Address 0x693c020 is 2,560 bytes inside a block of size 2,731 free'd
==11602==    at 0x4C2EDEB: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==11602==    by 0x4F81D28: PyMarshal_ReadLastObjectFromFile (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==    by 0x4F85A22: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==    by 0x4F872FF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==    by 0x4F88559: PyImport_ImportModuleLevel (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==    by 0x4EFF697: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==    by 0x4F4B1E2: PyObject_Call (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==    by 0x5021446: PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==    by 0x4EF45C5: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==    by 0x502201B: PyEval_EvalCodeEx (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==    by 0x4EF0B88: PyEval_EvalCode (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==    by 0x4F851B3: PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==  Block was alloc'd at
==11602==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==11602==    by 0x4F81CDF: PyMarshal_ReadLastObjectFromFile (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==    by 0x4F85A22: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==    by 0x4F872FF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==    by 0x4F88559: PyImport_ImportModuleLevel (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==    by 0x4EFF697: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==    by 0x4F4B1E2: PyObject_Call (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==    by 0x5021446: PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==    by 0x4EF45C5: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==    by 0x502201B: PyEval_EvalCodeEx (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==    by 0x4EF0B88: PyEval_EvalCode (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602==    by 0x4F851B3: PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
==11602== 
==11602== 
==11602== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11602==     in use at exit: 491,741 bytes in 204 blocks
==11602==   total heap usage: 3,301 allocs, 3,097 frees, 3,567,424 bytes allocated
==11602== 
==11602== LEAK SUMMARY:
==11602==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11602==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11602==      possibly lost: 1,072 bytes in 2 blocks
==11602==    still reachable: 490,669 bytes in 202 blocks
==11602==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11602== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==11602== 
==11602== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11602== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==11602== ERROR SUMMARY: 497 errors from 25 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

In my main, you need to know that I'm creating only one IA object.

Am I doing something wrong ? Or is it just the API ?

(This is not a duplicate because I run valgrind on my C++ executable and not Python, my c++ is running the script)

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use valgrind with Python C++ extensions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982036/how-can-i-use-valgrind-with-python-c-extensions)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if the duplicate's right, so please disagree if you want, but it may help you ignore a lot of the errors. Also: you should be checking the return value from (most of) your Python calls against `NULL`. That's how you know if an error has occurred.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but it stills remains an error : "Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==10564==    at 0x4FCE194: PyObject_Free (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0)". I checked all the return of Python function in C++ and no error message appeared.

Comment: A skim over your code suggests that you're definitely leaking `pFunc`, `toSend`, `pResult` and possibly `TlistMob`, `TlistPlayer`, `pDPosIA` (I don't really know much about those last three). I don't know if that's the issue with the uninitialized value though.

Comment: Also, you should not call `PyErr_Print()` unless there is an error to print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initially suggested [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982036/how-can-i-use-valgrind-with-python-c-extensions) as a duplicate. I don't think that's the case any more, but it still gives useful advice on removing false positives from the Valgrind output for Python programs.

Beyond that there are a number of specific issues with your program:

- No error checking - the Python C API typically uses a NULL return value to indicate an error. There are clearly various ways of writing error checking code, but I'd be tempted to go for something like

  ```
  IA::IA() :
  pModule(NULL), pDict(NULL), pFunc(NULL), pName(NULL) // initially null initialize everything
  {
    setenv("PYTHONPATH",".",1);
    Py_Initialize();

    // I don't think you actually use this line, so maybe remove it
    if (PyRun_SimpleString("import sys") == -1) goto error;

    pName = PyBytes_FromString((char*)"Test");
    if (!pName) goto error;
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    if (!pModule) goto error;
    pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
    if (!pDict) goto error;
    pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, "push_f");
    if (!pFunc) goto error;

    return; // completed OK

    error:
    Py_XDECREF(pName); // XDECREF is OK with NULL...
    Py_XDECREF(pModule);
    Py_XDECREF(pDict);
    Py_XDECREF(pFunc);
    PyErr_Print();
    throw std::runtime_error(""); // ??? - possibly get and use the error string
              // see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1418703/4657412
  }
  ```

  I'm aware people are suspicious of `goto` but in this case it's a reasonably clean way of jumping to an error handling block. You can structure it differently if you like.
- The destructor doesn't decref `pFunc`, which looks like a memory leak.
- `IA::LaunchIA` similarly is lacking working error checking.
- `IA::LaunchIA` never decrefs `toSend`, `pResult`, `TlistMob`, `TlistPlayer`, `pDPosIA`. Some of these are related to the incompleteness of the code you show, but if they aren't decrefed then you're leaking memory.
- You call `PyErr_Print()` without checking for an error. The documentation says:

  > Call this function only when the error indicator is set. (Otherwise it will cause a fatal error!)

  I suspect that this might be your biggest problem.

---

Those are all the issues I can see. Without a minimal complete example it's impossible to actually check what you're seeing. Given you're using C++ you might be well advised to use/make a decent, object oriented wrapper for `PyObject*` to avoid having to worry about reference counting yourself - Boost Python has one.